# Either redirect or show a message (Django)

Tags: python, django, redirect

Writing a reusable Django component:

Calling certain function of my component should either redirect to PayPal site (if the trial period is zero) or show the message to the user that he has registered and entered into a trial period.

The problem is that because the component is reusable, I don't know in advance how the message should be shown: It may be redirect to a page which shows the message or it may be a JavaScript based popup window, etc.

How to make a reusable Django method which can be customized in these ways?

Comment: In Django you have apps and MTVs not components. so you want to write a view?

Comment: I think it is better if you add some code here to show us what is your goal and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Define the redirect to PayPal as a dynamic method which could receive name/value pairs.

Then it could be easily overridden to return JSON with these name/value pairs to be used by JavaScript (for example to create a post form to PayPal and automatically submit it).